# Debugger wont make it past printf using GDB with VScode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gdb

I have been trying to debug on VScode I have a very simple program and every time I try to "step over" or "continue" the debugger breaks and gives me this error

```
"Unable to open 'libc-start.c': Unable to read file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+atlas.cselabs.umn.edu/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c'

(Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'vscode-remote://ssh-remote+atlas.cselabs.umn.edu/build/glibc-YYA7BZ/glibc-2.31/csu/libc-start.c'). "
```

The breakpoints after the printf are hollow grey so I assume the problem is with a printf. Having a debugger would be pointless if I can't even debug any files with print functions in them. BTW the code itself runs normally without a debugger. How could I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i =0;
    i++;
    i++;
    i++;
    printf("hello world");
    i++;
    int x = 10;
    x++;
    printf("i=%d  x=%d\n", i, x);  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your compiler removes those variables because they don't do anything. Thats why you can't break on those lines, they don't exist in the compiled binary.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The debugger works fine as I work with variables I and x. It only breaks when I step over the printf("hello\n"); from the i++.

Comment: put a `printf("i=%d  x=%d\n", i, x);  return 0;` at the end of the program to keep `i` and `x`

Comment: what if you do the debugging on a local VSC?

Comment: I added that printf you gave me and I get the same error. What do you mean by "local VSC"